# How to turn an email thread in Outlook into a Teams chat?

Tags: windows, windows-10, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-teams

Let's say there is an email thread in desktop Outlook with 10 participants that has gone out of control.  I seem to remember that back in the day, there was a way to take an email and make a Skype for Business conversation out of it with all the participants.

Is this possible with Microsoft Teams?

I see that Microsoft Teams Add-in is loaded in Outlook, but I am not sure what it actually does.

Comment: Glad to see your issue has been resolved. It's recommended to post your solution to answer, which would benefit others who also has similar issue.

Comment: @Jade Good idea. Will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question in case someone wants to do the same thing.

1. In Teams, go to Settings and make Teams the default IM client client for Outlook.  [image]
2. Then in Outlook, select an Email message, then click on the `...` menu, and select `Reply All with IM`

[image]

Comment: It would be better if you mark it as the answer :)

Comment: @Jade The site doesn't let you mark your own questions as the answer for a day.  It's marked now.